# CAKEPHP - I'm trying to input data from FORM to Database, but is not working

Tags: php, cakephp

I got a form that work correctly and it is generated by formHelper of CakePHP, there is one of the fields that are working correctly:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Briefing.titulo', array('class' => 'input-xxlarge', 'div' => 'controls', 'label' => false)); ?>
```

it goes to the database correctly, but, when i add another field in the form, like this:

```
 <?php echo $this->Form->input('Briefing.titulo2', array('class' => 'input-xxlarge', 'div' => 'controls', 'label' => false)); ?>
```

its not working , i'm sure that in the DB i have a field named *titulo2*

everything else from the form goes to the DB, but mine new piece does not.

What should i do?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try clearing the model cache (./tmp/cache/models)?

Comment: Thank you, it was the cache :D , i'm learning cake ! thank you very much

Comment: the question was tagged as duplicated, @npm asked me to edit it to look diferent, but for me, it is already different. I cant figure out how change it to look diferent because that was my doubt, and it is different from the other solution for the same problem. i dont know what can i do.

Comment: You received an automatic message when your question was [**closed as a duplicate**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates), suggesting to edit your question to make it different if you think the other question and the answers _doesn't address your issue_. Since your issue is exactly the one in the linked question, there isn't anything that you'd need to do, your question is a duplicate, no need to worry, keep on riding. See also **http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions**